# @onclick:preventDefault Not Work In Firefox

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

in my blazor app i need to call funtion when in click on a tag and preventDefault from a tag,
this work done in chrome but firefox preventDefault not work and when i clicked,go to href value,

my sample code:

```
<a href="" @onclick="@(() => SomeFunc("Hi"))" @onclick:preventDefault>
   @stats.Blocks
</a>
```

i use ASP.NET Core version 3.1.402 & Blazor 3.2.1

Comment: Can you share more code? It may be caused by code conflicts. And does console have errors in firefox?

Answer (score 0):

The above code is working well with Firefox latest version 83.0. If any issue please update your firefox browser and try again

Comment: My FireFox version is 83.0 and still isnt working!!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what is the exact issue? If possible can you please post an screen